# How to convert HashMap to JsonObject directly

Tags: java, json

I checked that I can convert the hashmap to json using Gson, but it's giving String. Then I've to convert this string to JsonObject.

Is there any way that I can convert the hashmap to JsonObject directly using gson

Comment: You _might_ want to show some code. I don't know Gson but if it works like the other mappers (and I'd guess it does) it first converts everything to JsonObject and then formats that to a string so getting a JsonObject instead should just be a matter of how you do your calls.

Comment: No, not '*might*'. Please do show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJsonTree(hashmap).getAsJsonObject();
```

This is what I was able to glean from reading the [API](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1)
It seems to me you want to use the .toJsonTree method instead of the .toJson method and then get the JsonElement as a JsonObject